# Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

As part of the Sitecore upgrade updated `.net framework 4.7 to 4.8` and getting below exception.

Description:

```
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'
```

Source Error:

```
Line 142:
Line 143:    @{
Line 144:        var title = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Browser Title"]?.Value ?? Sitecore.Context.Item.DisplayName;
Line 145:        if (Sitecore.Context.Item.IsDerivedFrom(Website.Areas.test.Constants.SitecoreTemplates.BASE_PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_ID))
Line 146:        {
```

Source File: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc1033.cm\Areas\test\Views\Shared\DefaultLayout.cshtml    Line: 144`

In visual studio build got succeeded, post deploy in webroot getting above error.

Regards,
Reddy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the Invalid expression term error, please make sure your `web.config` has the `DotNetCompilerPlatform`

Try adding this into your `Web.config` and it should resolve your issue.

```
 <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, 
        Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Ref: [Invalid expression term](http://www.bridgemiles.net/Solr-Search)

Hope this will solve your issue.